# Symbolic breakpoint for App Transport Security block?

Tags: ios, ios9, app-transport-security

I have Application Transport Security enabled in my app. If a third party library attempts to load a non secure http resource I get the following logged to the console:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure.

Can I add a symbolic breakpoint (or some other mechanism) to let me know that a resource has been blocked in a more noticeable way?

*Edit: I'm not looking to disable ATS, just get more reliably informed when it blocks a resource*